# Printing NDWI and NDVI comparision graph

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, normalized-difference-water-index

Trying to print the chart for both NDVI and NDWI

```
  function addNDVI(image) {
            var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B4', 'B3']);
        return image.addBands(ndvi);
            }
    var filtered = L7.filterDate('2000-01-01', '2019-12-31')
     .filterBounds(mumbai);
    var with_ndvi = filtered.map(addNDVI);
    var rgb_vis = {min: 0, max: 0.1, bands: ['B3', 'B2', 'B1']};
    //Map.addLayer(filtered.median(), rgb_vis, 'RGB (median)');
    var greenest = with_ndvi.qualityMosaic('nd');
    //Map.addLayer(greenest, rgb_vis, 'RGB (greenest pixel)'); 
    //print(ui.Chart.image.series(with_ndvi.select('nd'), mumbai));

    /********** NDWI***************/

    var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_8DAY_NDWI')
                          .filterDate('1999-01-01', '2019-12-31')
                          .filterBounds(mumbai);
        var colorized = dataset.select('NDWI');
        var colorizedVis = {
          min: 0.0,
          max: 1.0,
          palette: ['0000ff', '00ffff', 'ffff00', 'ff0000', 'ffffff'],
        };

        Map.setCenter(72.88, 19.154, 10);
       // Map.addLayer(colorized, colorizedVis, 'Colorized');
        print(dataset.select("NDWI"));
        print(with_ndvi.select("nd"));

       var y1 = ee.Array(with_ndvi.get('nd'));
       var y2 = ee.Array(colorized.get('NDWI'))
        //concat
        var yValues = ee.Array.cat([y1, y2], 1);

       // code to print chart of ndvi and ndwi 
        var chart = ui.Chart.array.values(yValues, 0, mumbai)
        .setSeriesNames(['B5', 'B6'])
        .setOptions({
          title: 'LC8 TOA B4 vs. {B5,B6}',
          hAxis: {'title': 'B4'},
          vAxis: {'title': '{B5,B6}'},
          pointSize: 3,
    });

    // Print the chart.
    print(chart);
```

Error:

> Error generating chart: Array: Parameter 'values' is required.
>
> Array: Parameter 'values' is required.

Comment: Can you please update the question with a complete example that will produce the error you mentioned? When I run the above code chunk, I get the error that `"L7" is not defined in this scope.` which is because you have not declared what `L7` is.